# re.search() hung

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

This code snippet intends to search for a regex match on each line of the supplied file. **re.search() gets hung at a line containing "#" character 3e+5 times in the file.**

---

What could be the solution to this problem?

```
import re
print "Started..."
exp = "(.*)\$\$\$Uniqueterm:(.*)"
with open("sample.txt", 'r') as file:
    for line in file: 
        if re.search(exp, line):
            print "Found match: " + re.search(exp,line).groups()[1].strip()
    print "File finished..."
```

Sample input file (sample.txt):

```
abc
pqr 
##### (3e+5 times '#' in a single line)
xyz
$$$Uniqueterm: Match it
qaz
```

Expected Output:

```
Match it
```

Comment: How large is `sample.txt` ?

Comment: What is the actual data you are trying to match?  Your regex pattern does not match the sample data at all.

Comment: Added the sample data I'm trying to match. The file size is 3.84 MB with the exact same data provided with the question.

Comment: Does running *exactly* the posted code produce the hang?

Comment: Yes, It gives the following output and then gets hung: "Started...". If we remove the line containing "#"s , we get the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex engine can reach high complexties, specially when it must backtrack, like in your case.

So when the expression to search for is long and you have groups that must be computed with a lot of trial & error (i.e. backtracking), the search can take ages (see [a famous example of regex failure on StackOverflow network](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016)).

> On July 20, 2016 we experienced a 34 minute outage starting at 14:44 UTC. It took 10 minutes to identify the cause, 14 minutes to write the code to fix it, and 10 minutes to roll out the fix to a point where Stack Overflow became available again.
>
> The direct cause was a malformed post that caused one of our regular expressions to consume high CPU on our web servers. The post was in the homepage list, and that caused the expensive regular expression to be called on each home page view.
>   ...
>
> **This regular expression has been replaced with a substring function.**

I'd propose a workaround since you don't really need regex here, using `str.split` would do and is fast, since it just searches for the substring (`O(N)` approach) then creates 2 strings, which is equivalent of what you're trying to do with regular expressions:

```
a = "foo$$$Uniqueterm:bar"
g1,g2 = a.split("$$$Uniqueterm:")
print(g1,g2)
```

result

```
foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `re.search` with a regex that starts with `(.*)`. `re.search` looks for a match at any starting position, meaning it has to start a search from every possible starting index until it finds a match or runs out of positions to search from. The leading `(.*)` forces a scan of the *entire string* starting from the search start position, for *every starting position*.

It's classic catastrophic backtracking, just with part of the backtracking implicit in the use of `re.search` instead of built into the regex itself. You could adjust the regex to eliminate the catastrophic backtracking, but why use a regex at all? Basic methods like `str.split` or `str.find` can do the job just fine. Jean-François Fabre's answer shows one way to do it.

Comment: well, that didn't get that much votes... I don't understand since it's a nice regex question, with correct answers :)